# How to convert 'X hours Y minutes' time string into z minutes in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have been stuck with php date time conversion. I have to convert a dynamic time string like 'd days X hours Y minutes' into the total minutes. This time string is dynamic and returned by some third party API. This could be like 'X hours Y minutes', 'Y minutes' etc..

Please help me if someone is having any clue for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Does this API provide no other format?

Comment: How about using regular expressions to return hours and minutes seperately. For instance:
    ([\d]+)[\s]+(?i)(?=hours)

([\d]+)[\s]+(?i)(?=minutes)

Comment: George, there is no other way to get a specific time format from the API. This is the main issue.

Comment: @VinodKumar so can you give an example string?

Comment: @Ghost, example like '3 hours 23 minutes'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joe replied, here a little push on your way. Note the + in front, as we are adding. We could turn them both into date objects and do a diff() to get the mentioned DateInterval of course.

```
$apiTimeStamp   = strtotime("+1 weeks 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds");
echo abs($apiTimeStamp - time()) / 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<?php
$min=0; 
$arr = '1 hours 20 minutes';

$a=explode(' ',$arr);
if($a[1] == 'hours')
{
    $min = $min+ $a[0]*60;
}
if($a[3] == 'minutes')
{
    $min =$min+ $a[2];
}
if($a[1] == 'minutes')
{
    $min = $min+ $a[0];
}
echo "'".$min." minutes"."'";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $apistring = "10 Hours 15 Minutes";
  preg_match("#([\d]+)[/\s]+(?i)(?=hours)#", $apistring, $hours);
  preg_match("#([\d]+)[/\s]+(?i)(?=minutes)#", $apistring, $minutes);
  if (is_numeric($hours[1])==true) {
    $intHourMinutes = $hours[1]*60;
    }
  else {
    $intHourMinutes = 0;
  }
  if (is_numeric($minutes[1])==true) {
    $intMinutes = $minutes[1];
    }
  else {
    $intMinutes = 0;
  }
  $totalminutes=$intHourMinutes+$intMinutes;
  print_r($totalminutes);
  ?>
```